# View contents of ActiveRecord::Relation Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have produced an AR query which has returned an object of the above type. The object has the name of `#<Review id: 26>`

I am learning how to do advanced join queries and I would like to know if I have produced the desired object. It is a pain in the neck to have to assign the object to a variable and then slowly figure out how to iterate over it's contents using the data you hope is contained within.

Thank you.

Comment: It would be really helpful of you could provide a bit more details. I.e. what exactly the queries you ran were, the relationship etc etc.

Comment: Perhaps what you are looking for is .inspect, as in:  start up an irb terminal session, run your query, then object.inspect to see what it contains.  I would hope that from the query, you know what model is returned (a Review?), and you just have to validate that the returned model matches/passes your criteria.

Comment: @sohaibbbhatti, I am looking for more of a general approach, not specific to a given query.

Comment: @railsdog, I tried .inspect on my relational object, but unfortunately this still gave me #<Review id: 26>

Comment: You can always add .to_sql and try to make some sense from there?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are looking for `variable_name.to_json`.